# Generate unique sequence ID

Tags: c++, algorithm

how to Generate a unique sequence ID to be stored in unsigned long ?
Getting seconds elapsed after 1970 would have been good idea but requirement is within a second the id might be updated , so second wont be unique !

Comment: How is it supposed to be unique? Globally? Withing a single run?

Comment: One some platforms a `long` will be too short to do anything random/independently generated, you'd be forced to simply count and keep track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your requirements are to pick something pseudo random, fast, reliably unique, and not used for requirement for crytographic security purposes, I offer up the following

On Windows X86:

[__rdtsc()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twchhe95%28VS.80%29.aspx)  - is about as good of a sequential number as it gets.  XOR the upper 32-bits of the return value with the lower 32-bits.  As the lower 32-bits will cycle every couple of seconds

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <intrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t GetPseudoRandomNumber()
{
    uint64_t t = _time64(NULL);
    uint64_t cpu = __rdtsc();
    uint32_t result;
    cpu = cpu ^ t;
    result = (cpu >> 32) ^ (cpu & 0xffffffff);
    return result;
}

uint32_t GetPseudoRandomNumber2()
{
    GUID guid = {};
    uint32_t* pValue = (uint32_t*)&guid;
    uint32_t result;

    CoCreateGuid(&guid);

    result = pValue[0] ^ pValue[1] ^ pValue[2] ^ pValue[3];

    return result;
}
```

Other sources of entropy include GetTickCount() (unique to the millisecond)

On Linux:
   Just read 4 bytes from [/dev/urandom](http://myonlineusb.wordpress.com/2011/06/10/what-is-the-difference-between-devrandom-and-devurandom/)

Comment: thought of using GetTickCount() but it will wrap upto 0 after 49 days.Requirement is atleast 6 months of uninterrupted generation. So now trying with your first suggestion .Thank you selbie

Comment: one more querry here : You say lowe 32 bit will cycle every couple of seconds . can you ellaborate ? doing this will the number generated is always unique .Thank you

Comment: The rtdsc instruction is the sequence number of the x86 instruction at that moment.  It returns a 64-bit number.  You could easily "downcast" it to a 32-bit number.  Let's say your CPU clocks at 2ghz.  So if your code calls rdtsc() a second time at exactly 2 seconds later since the first call, a cast to a 32-bit int can possibly be the same as before.  So if your sequence number is 32-bits, you'll want to mix in the upper 32-bits.  Example above.

Comment: You said "unsigned long", so I assumed 32-bit sequence number.  Hence, the long winded XOR operation to better guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: @selbie:does  rtdsc will reset the number at machine restart ?This might render the sequence id non unique ?

Comment: Good point.  XOR it again with the date/time.    I've also benchmarked a likely better way - just call CoCreateGuid and XOR up the result.  Code updated above.

Comment: @selbie: Great improvisation ! should work , testing in progress :-)

Comment: @selbie : hey thanks its working , i am getting a 10 digit ( some times 9 digit unique number). Is it possible to reduce it to 8 digits keeping it unique ? thanks in advance

Comment: @selbie : I understand sir . I appreciate your time spent on my queries , yet i have this doubt whether you modulus solution preserves the uniqueness of the number ? Thank you . < you may obstain from replying ,your wish >

Answer (score 7):

Unless you provide more information about your requirements, it's going to be hard to come up with an answer besides:

```
unsigned long next_id = 0;

unsigned long new_id() {
    return next_id++;
}
```

Comment: could be made persistent, or from a server, but as you stated, this is part of requirements.

Comment: @315viky: Get a database then, but really - we can't answer your real question if you don't tell us what you really need.

Comment: @MSalters :Requirement is to generate a sequence ID upto 10 digits long , held in an unsigned long.It should be persistent . Within a second , there may be more then one sequence ID required so time elapsed after 1970 wont be an option.Thank you

Comment: Who would notice that you reused a sequence ID after a crash, and how? Obviously there is some kind of external observer that has a persistent state of its own. Can't you query that at startup for the highest ID it's aware of?

Answer (score 0):

use milliseconds elapsed after 1970

Comment: Be careful that although many APIs expose milli/micro/nanosecond precision they don't actually track to that precision. You may only ever get precision to 1s, 1ms, or something else.  So despite several microseconds passing, you'll still get the same time value.

Answer (score 0):

Try use: `srand ( time(NULL) );`

Answer (score 0):

How you generate the unique_ids is a useful question - but you seem to be making a counter productive assumption about *when* you generate them!

My point is that you do not need to generate these unique id's at the time of creating your rows, because they are essentially independent of the data being inserted.

What I do is pre-generate unique id's for future use, that way I can take my own sweet time and absolutely guarantee they are unique, and there's no processing to be done at the time of the insert.

For example I have an orders table with order_id in it.  This id is generated on the fly when the user enters the order, incrementally 1,2,3 etc forever.  The user does not need to see this internal id.

Then I have another table - unique_ids with (order_id, unique_id).  I have a routine that runs every night which pre-loads this table with enough unique_id rows to more than cover the orders that might be inserted in the next 24 hours.  (If I ever get 10000 orders in one day I'll have a problem - but that would be a good problem to have!)

This approach guarantees uniqueness and takes any processing load away from the insert transaction and into the batch routine, where it does not affect the user.