# Unique 10 digit Sequence ID - 200 IDs/Sec

Tags: c++

I need to generate unique ID in c++. I'm looking at almost 200 IDs per second and these IDs should not repeat atleast for the next 30 days. The IDs should be 9 or 10 digits long.
Also these should not repeat if my service is restarted or if my machine is restarted.

i checked out the following link
[Generate unique sequence ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368503/generate-unique-sequence-id)

It's almost the same requirement as mine. 
But the problem i faced with that piece of code is the ID length.
At times it used to generate as low as 2 digit IDs.
I confirmed this with a test driver.

Your inputs will be much appreciated.

Comment: I presume you have tried just simply incrementing a variable by one each time you need a new ID? You can deal with the service/machine restart scenario by saving the current ID to a file before exiting then reading it on start-up.

Comment: @Insilico -> yes, i thought about it. but in case there is a crash, or a abrubt restart, this will go for a toss.

Answer (score 3):

As a first approximation, you could try something like this:

```
unsigned long genUniqueID()
{
  const unsigned long MIN_ID = 1e8; // 9 digit number
  const unsigned long MAX_IDs_SEC = 200;
  static unsigned long nextID = MIN_ID + getSecondsSinceStartOfMonth() * MAX_IDs_SEC;
  return nextID++;
}
```

Obviously there are two constants to tune. This solution wouldn't work if the average IDs generated per second during an uninterrupted run of your program exceeded `MAX_IDs_SEC`, so you will want to make sure that value is high enough, or otherwise throttle calling this function too often.

Comment: +1: I like the idea of incorporating the system time into the ID so that you can restart the process without having to store the ID. However, using the number of seconds since the start of the month can cause IDs to be reused (imagine the function gets called on the first second of january, then the process stops, and it's restart again on the first second of and then again on the first second of february).

Comment: @FrerichRaabe If it's restarted on the first second of February, then it's been 30 days since we assigned some ID's in the first second of January, so we're OK. If the program can be expected to be restarted in less than a second, then you could initialize `nextID` with something like `MIN_ID + getMillisecondsSinceStartOfMonth()`. I seriously doubt this process would be restarting faster than 1ms, and `MAX_IDs_SEC` would implicitly be 1000 which is much higher than OP's expected load.

Comment: @SchighSchagh-> how will this be unique if i'm generating, say, 200 IDs per sec? MIN_ID, getSecondsSinceStartOfMonth() & MAX_IDs_SEC .. all the three will have same value at that particular instant of time, correct?

Comment: @PraveenKeshavamurthy do you know how `static` variables work inside a function? `nextID` would be initialized as specified __the first time the function is called__. On subsequent calls, the `static` variable is not re-initialized. Instead, it keeps whatever value it had the last time the function returned. Thanks to the `++`, the variable `nextID` will contain a different number next time it is called, and it won't be re-initialized.

Comment: @SchighSchagh -> Sorry, failed to notice that it's a Static variable. Got it.

Comment: @PraveenKeshavamurthy Sure. Again, this won't _guarantee_ robustness in the face of restarts. The only way to guarantee that would be for the function to initialize the static variable by reading from a file, and every time it is called, it would have to first write the `nextID` to disk so that if the program does anything with the ID then crashes, it won't re-generate that ID on restart. If your safety demands were that extreme, you would also have to be careful to force the OS to flush the data to permanent storage before returning from the function, which would kill your throughput.

Comment: @SchighSchagh: What if the function gets called on the first second of February and then on the first second of March (note that februrary has less than 30 days)? I think it would be better to just use a unix time stamp.

Comment: @SchighSchagh: I thought about all this & would like to extend the same for a 6 months validity. something like GetSecondsFromtheStartoftheYr(). So for eg., assume 6 months, total no. of seconds -> 180*24*3600 = 15,552,000 -> Total JobIDs -> 15,552,000 * 200 = 3,110,400,000 -> Max Job ID = 3,210,400,000 ... Max Value that can be stored in Unsigned long is 4,294,967,295.. So my IDs still fit into Unsigned Long variable and is valid for 6 months.. Also i'm not looking at restart within a second.. so even that should be taken care..

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to generate 200 IDs per second, and you want to continue doing so (without repeating an ID) you need to be able to generate 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 200 = 518,400,000 IDs. If an ID should be at least 9 digits long, each ID should be (assuming you use decimal representation) larger or equal to 100,000,000 (the smallest number with 9 digits).

So ideally you'd have a function returning a value of a type which can hold the values between 100,000,000 and 618,400,000. Both values are smaller than the largest unsigned 32bit value (4,294,967,295), so you could just use that:

```
static uint32_t getNextId() {
  static uint32_t lastId = 99999999;
  return ++lastId;
}
```

Keep calling this function, it will yield a new ID on every call and they won't repeat in 30 days if you call the function 200 times per second.

If your process is started and stopped during those 30 days, just save the last used ID to a file when the process stops, and restore the ID when the process starts again.

Comment: Is a good start but this will restart when he restarts the service.

Comment: @RedX: Right, that's why I wrote the last paragraph.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe -> My only doubt here is, what if the service doesn't exit gracefully? how do i handle that error scenario?